Outperforming as a freelancer
I started working on a project last year as a freelancer.
I didn't like this project at all: messy architecture, unconventional project structure etc.
There was a precondition which was: a mission of 3 months.
In the middle of the second week, my boss contacted me asking to stay as a permanent freelancer, after having produced a document the PO liked, apparently.
I was reluctant, since I didn't like the project, and I was already working on my departure.
I was planning to finish my three months, and add a fourth, then I decided to stay after the end of the milestone, beyond the summer.
The strengths of the project was in Agile using Jira, and the Product Owner was doing a good job.
The PO told me in a cheerful way that I must stay, and spend a decade or two on this project. I decided to stay, and then I shutdown all invitations on LinkedIn.
During the last previous months, priorities were fast changing. I had to switch topics several times.
I noticed the PO was always resorting to me to support or unblock a colleague, knowing that I was the most recent element in the team.
I worked on a very difficult task, and I noticed that the most difficult tasks were for me.
I had to deploy a lot of energy to understand why something was not working.
I found out it was due to the bad structure I did recommend early enough to tackle.
I always talk about improvements but my colleagues didn't care at all, especially during retrospective meetings.
A breakthrough, I did an unprecedented action, which is to speak to other teams like R&D, and I initiated in depth topics for better product quality.
The PO also included me to attend final clients meetings.
On my first anniversary, I noticed I was working on the hardest tasks, the workload and topics increased, my teammates were not asked to make more effort, but I was asked to make more efforts to help my teammates.
I was expecting a raise as an encouragement, since I went beyond what is expected, I went out of the box.
I spoke to my boss about the raise, and it was the first time I saw a hostile face.
Long story short, I spoke to person 1, they said speak to person 2, person 2 said speak to person 3 etc.
Isn't it obvious that I deserve a raise, knowing that I have an average or may below average rate ?
Curiously enough, I didn't get much LinkedIn invitations as before, but anyway, I updated my CV and started applying again.
Is it bad to interrupt a job and disappoint the employer, knowing  that I have been qualified as a "nomad" with fastly changing employers?

Are you working as a freelancer or a contractor for the company ? Do they pay you by the hours or by fixed payment per the project ?

Does you contract with your company say anything about salary raise ? Full-time employees do have raises for sure. For contractors, it may be more difficult to get a raise. Great contractors also get raises and may be converted to full-time employees.

If you're still a contractor, you can simply say "Here's what it will cost you to renew the contract. If you aren't interested, I can find work elsewhere " If you're actually a salaried employee you can try that too, but there's no automatic deadline for them to decide by,.

I see no question here. You are probably not the first person in the workforce being paid less than they deserve. What can we help you with?

You seem resentful of being assigned the difficult tasks. If you want to renegotiate your billing rate you will have to be prepared to walk away from the job. I don’t see a question that we can answer

A raise isn't a reward. That's a bonus.

@Job_September_2020, I have a daily rate and I get paid every worked day.

@Job_September_2020, I confronted my boss and she said I needed to be verbal about a raise, since I expected an automatic raise because I was very competent and the PO incited me to stay. Freelancers only need to discuss the raise.

@nvoigt, in my CV, I have basically short experiences. Am I wrong asking for a raise because they make me feel like I am unreasonable.

If you want to be paid what you are worth you probably should have kept freelancing, in that position when you are asked to renew your response is my rate is X and if they accept that great if not you move on to someone who will pay.

I'm going to be honest, if you communicate on the job like this question you are going to have trouble getting ahead.  A post written like a list of PowerPoint bullets is a tough read.
My recommendation is this:  If you think you are not getting paid what you should be paid you need to look for other options to understand your market worth.  Comparing your work to that of you colleagues is a quick path to demotivation and disappointment.  My second is that if you work for companies who charge out your time, recognize how hard it is to change the cost to the client and thus how difficult it is to actually give you a raise.


Isn't it obvious that I deserve a raise, knowing that I have an
average or may below average rate?

Possibly, but most companies operate on the assumption that they have the power to avoid giving you that money.
The current state of affairs supplies evidence that, in their mind, they may be right. You keep taking on more responsibilities, and more technically challenging tasks, without ever demanding more money. The only way you can definitively prove otherwise is to get a job someplace else.
Generally the best way to get salary increases in modern industry, for at least a few generations now, is to move jobs. If you were to, e.g., take your current skills elsewhere (for a significant salary  boost), stay there a few years, and then move back to the current company (for another big boost), you'd find you were doing much better than if you'd stayed in your current position the whole time.


Isn't it obvious that I deserve a raise, knowing that I have an average or may below average rate ?

If they're impressed with you for delivering above-average work for a below-average rate, then why do you think they're going to want to change that equation now?
Why do you think they'd be as happy with paying you market rate, as they are with paying you less which you've been accepting all this time?
Just vote with your feet and move to a different employer.

I am not paid less the market rate. Compared to the work I have been doing in the last few months, I started to do expert work. If I have to do expert work, I have got to get an expert rate. If not, then at least to have a progressive rate.
